# How can I load a url (path) of a picture or others in a file of your build (prod) with webpack

Tags: javascript, angularjs, webpack

I have some questions about webpack and the interaction with the path of libraries.

This is my webpack-config.js:

```
var path = require('path'),
    webpack = require("webpack"),
    libPath = path.join(__dirname, 'lib'),
    distPath = path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin'),
    os = require('os'),
    ImageminPlugin = require('imagemin-webpack-plugin').default,
    OptimizeCssAssetsPlugin = require('optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin'),
    CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin'),
    webpackUglifyJsPlugin = require('webpack-uglify-js-plugin'),
    ProgressBarPlugin = require('progress-bar-webpack-plugin'); // To be deleted when webpack will accept the flag --progress in the devserver and not only in the command line

var cf = {
        entry: path.join(libPath, 'index.js'),
        output: {
            path: path.join(distPath),
            filename: 'bundle-[hash:6].js'
        },
        resolveLoader: { root: path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules') },
        module: {
            loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                loader: 'file?name=lib/templates/[name]-[hash].html'
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                loaders: ['style', 'css', 'sass', 'resolve-url', 'sass?sourceMap']
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loaders: ["style-loader", "css-loader"]
            },
            {
                test: /\.woff(2)?(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
                loader: 'url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff&&name=lib/font/[name]-[hash].[ext]'
            },
            {
                test: /\.jpe?g$|\.gif$|\.png$/,
                loaders: ['file?hash=sha512&digest=hex&name=lib/img/[name]-[hash].[ext]',
                        'image-webpack?bypassOnDebug&optimizationLevel=7&interlaced=false'] // I write for the moment lib/img because i have not the choice but i don't want write in the same folder that the dev env
            },
            {
                test: /\.ttf$|\.eot$|\.wav$|\.svg$/,
                loader: "file?name=lib/font/[name]-[hash].[ext]"
            },
            {
                test: /\.json$/,
                loaders: ["raw-loader", "file?name=lib/languages/[name]-[hash].[ext]"]
            },
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules)/,
                loaders: ['ng-annotate?add=true', 'babel']
            }
          ]
        },
        devServer: {
          port: 3001,
          compress:true,
          colors:true
        },

        plugins: [
            // HtmlWebpackPlugin: Simplifies creation of HTML files to serve your webpack bundles : https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-webpack-plugin
            new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
                inject: true,
                filename: 'index.html',
                title: 'MY_CUSTOM_APP',
                template: path.join(libPath, 'index.html')
            }),

            // Deduplication: find duplicate dependencies & prevents duplicate inclusion : https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/optimization#deduplication
            new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),

            // OccurenceOrderPlugin: Assign the module and chunk ids by occurrence count. : https://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#occurenceorderplugin
            new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),

            new OptimizeCssAssetsPlugin({
              cssProcessor: require('cssnano'),
              cssProcessorOptions: { discardComments: {removeAll: true } },
              canPrint: true
            }),

            new ImageminPlugin({
              disable: false,
              optipng: {
                optimizationLevel: 3
              },
              gifsicle: {
                optimizationLevel: 1
              },
              jpegtran: {
                progressive: false
              },
              svgo: {
              },
              pngquant: null, // pngquant is not run unless you pass options here
              plugins: []
           }),

           // a faire uniquement en prod
           new webpackUglifyJsPlugin ({
             cacheFolder: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist/cached_uglify/'),
             sourceMap: false,
             minimize: false,
             compressor: {
               warnings: false
             }
           }),
           new ProgressBarPlugin({format: '  build [:bar] ' + (':percent') + ' (:elapsed seconds)'})
        ]
};

module.exports = cf;
```

This is my call of angular directive:

```
<complete-block
                 header-img="./lib/img/image.jpg"
                 body-title="{{ 'BODY_TITLE' | translate }}"
                 body-text="{{ 'LOREM_1' | translate }}"></complete-block>
```

My problem is about the url for the picture.

In my dist build ( production), I have only a root folder dist and then under it, I have the img folder. 
In more, the picture has a hash so finally I have something like that: `dist/img/mypicture-56567465456354354.png` instead of `lib/img/mypicture.png`.

How can I load it with the hash in the directive and also if it's not the same path between the dev env and the  prod env ?

Sorry if it's trivial, all of this is new for me and I didn't find a solution about it :/

Thank you ! :)

Edit 1 (07/01/2017) : My work is opensource, so you can find it on github here: `https://github.com/kevincaradant/web-template-webpack`

The picture / link is here :

```
.../lib/components/home/home.component.js
.../lib/components/home/home.html
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to require the image in the js file. It will give you the path of the image to use in the code. eg :

```
var image = require('./lib/img/image.jpg'); // returns 'dist/img/mypicture-56567465456354354.png'

<complete-block
    header-img="{{ image }}"
    body-title="{{ 'BODY_TITLE' | translate }}"
    body-text="{{ 'LOREM_1' | translate }}"></complete-block>
```

Comment: I don't understand your answer. You talk about require ( which is a javascript code ) and just after that, you write a piece of html code. Can you be more specific please ?

Comment: Please, have a look at the edit 1 on my initial post. You will find my repository.